# .NET Core app with multiple database contextes does not generate tables in all DbContexts

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, web-deployment

I have made an OData server with `.NET core 3.1`.

**In this application I have 2 database contexts. One of them for the app itself (AppDbContext) and one for the account management and authentication (AccountDbContext).**

I have a `ServiceExtensions` like this:

```cs
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
            
    public static void ConfigureMySqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"),
                mysqlOptions => {
                    mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(5, 4, 3), ServerType.MySql));
                });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AccountDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"),
                mysqlOptions => {
                    mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(5, 4, 3), ServerType.MySql));
                });
        });

    }
        
}
```

And in the `startup.cs` I will call the `ConfigureMySqlContext` function as following:

```cs
public class Startup
{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. 
        // I use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.ConfigureMySqlContext(Configuration);
        }
}

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .CreateDbIfNotExists()
            .Run();
    }

    private static IHost CreateDbIfNotExists(this IHost host)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

            var accountDbContext = services.GetRequiredService<AccountDbContext>();
            accountDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var appDbContext = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
            appDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                
        }

        return host;
    }
}
```

The aim of this code is, to generate the needed tables in both contexts inside the database.
The problem is, when I publish this application to the server, and when the app will run for the first time, it will only generate and initiate the tables that are in the `AppDbContext`. Why? Because it is placed before `AccountDbContext`.

If I change the `ConfigureMySqlContext` function as follow and publish the app again:

```cs
public static class ServiceExtensions
{
            
    public static void ConfigureMySqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<AccountDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"),
                mysqlOptions => {
                    mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(5, 4, 3), ServerType.MySql));
                });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("MysqlConnection"),
                mysqlOptions => {
                    mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(5, 4, 3), ServerType.MySql));
                });
        });       
    }        
}
```

Then it will be the tables inside the `AccountDbContext` which will be initiated in the database after the first run.

Comment: Are you using the same database for both?

Comment: yes, sure. Also I tried to define 2 different connection string with 2 different names in the `appsettings.json` for each. But it wasn't helpful.

Comment: I mean something like this: `"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MysqlConnection1": "server=localhost;port=3306;userid=root;password=;database=xyz;TreatTinyAsBoolean=true;",
    "MysqlConnection2": "server=localhost;port=3306;userid=root;password=;database=xyz;TreatTinyAsBoolean=true;"
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that at it's core, `EnsureCreated` has very simple semantics, which can be modeled as:

```cs
if (!database.exists()) {
   database.create();
}
```

where `exists()` checks for the existance of the database, without inspecting if the tables inside the database.

The end result of it is that if the database is not completely empty, `EnsureCreated()` will have no effect.

There are two ways of approaching the issue:

1. Split up the database into two. This is the solution that EntityFramework likes best.

However, if it's not an option, look into:

2. Look into the `IRelationalDatabaseCreator.CreateTables()` method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.irelationaldatabasecreator?view=efcore-5.0

Here is a possible solution:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .CreateDbIfNotExists()
            .Run();
    }

    private static IHost CreateDbIfNotExists(this IHost host)
    {
        using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var accountDbContext = services.GetRequiredService<AccountDbContext>();
                accountDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                var accountDbCreator = accountDbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>();
                accountDbCreator.CreateTables();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }

            try
            {
                var appDbContext = services.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
                appDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
                var appDbCreator = appDbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>();
                appDbCreator.CreateTables();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }

        return host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. If you like support your answer with a small snippet of code.

Comment: I assume you need to get the `IRelationalDatabaseCreator` as a service. I'm not sure how the database is specified.

Comment: I found [this](https://medium.com/@Usurer/ef-core-check-if-db-exists-feafe6e36f4e) article. But the problem is my `appDbContext.Database` does not have `GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>` function. 
Do you have any sample application?

Comment: Or here too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/ensure-created
It does not say how `DbContext` should have `GetService`

Comment: I found the solution. It just needs the following 2 using statements:

`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;` and `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;`