# using in C# vs. import in Java

Tags: java, c#

I am coming from Java and C++ background. However, I am doing a C# application at the moment and one thing made me confused.

In Java when I import a package, it means I can access the classes that are placed in that package. For example, here I imported the `ArrayList` class from package `java.util`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ArrayListUtilization {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(3);
        myList.add(3);
        myList.add(2);
        myList.add(1);

        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Recently I had a problem in my c-sharp app, that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66267578/net-core-app-with-multiple-database-contextes-does-not-generate-tables-in-all-d). The funny part in my point of view is, when I added the following snippet of code:

```cs
var accountDbContext = services.GetRequiredService<AccountDbContext>();
accountDbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
var accountDbCreator = accountDbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>();
accountDbCreator.CreateTables();
```

I saw an error as following:

[image]

> Error CS1929  'AccountDbContext' does not contain a definition for
> 'GetService' and the best extension method overload
> 'ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService(IServiceProvider)'
> requires a receiver of type 'IServiceProvider'

and from the error text, I understood `accountDbContext` object does not have `GetService` function. But when I press on `show potential fixes`, then it suggests me to add a `using` statement.

[image]

And it was the real fix. However, my question is what is the effect of this `using` statement on my object? The object is an instantiation of its class. How can adding a `using` statement effect on my object and add a function to it?

Comment: Using is like import in Java, I am from Java background and I switched to C# well a few methods need importing (as you may already know it) or you can do it like :Microsoft.EntitiyFrameworkSomethingSomething.Infra.Method.Function (pretty long) and that is an uneasy way of doing something in C# maybe ur class needs it? I am not sure

Comment: Maybe ur class needs it I am not sure

Comment: [What are extension methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods) (maybe)

Comment: What is the relation then? I can access my object. This using will remove the error of missing function.

Comment: @John Thanks, I will follow up that keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that what you are actually calling an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) here:

```
accountDbContext.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>();
```

`accountDbContext` does not have a method called `GetService`. [`GetService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.accessorextensions.getservice?view=efcore-5.0) is declared in [`AccessorExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.accessorextensions?view=efcore-5.0), and the above line is just syntactic sugar for:

```
AccessorExtensions.GetService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>(accountDbContext);
```

Now it should make sense that you need to add a using directive for the class in which the extension method is declared, in order to access the extension method.